# Python Flask: forbidden access to static files in aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda

I deployed my flask app on the aws lambda service, although the app works fine, it cannot get .css and .js files from `static` folder, `403 FORBIDDEN` error is returned when trying to access them.

I think the issue might be in my IAM user roles I use to deploy my application. I gave him following roles: `AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess`, `AdministratorAccess` and `AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator` as well as `IAMFullAccess` user group but to no effect. I'm using `serverless` to deploy my app.

Here are my app files:

`serverless.yml`

```
service: serverless-flask

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: run.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.9
  stage: dev
  region: eu-central-1

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - venv/**

functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi_handler.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: "ANY {proxy+}"
```

Project files:

```
├── my_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── main.css
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   └── main.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── package-lock.json
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── layout.html
│   └── utils
│       ├── reader.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── serverless.yml
```

App creation file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="static", static_url_path="/static")

    @app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
    def index():
        sample_data = {
            'data': 'sample data'
        }
        return render_template("index.html", data=sample_data)

    return app
```

Comment: can you check if the static files are actually part of the zip bundle?

Comment: @Korgen Yes, they are inside the .zip bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Just had to rename folder `static` to something else, for some reason AWS blocks access to folder named `static`.
I renamed folder to `public` but it works with any name as long as it's not `static`

Here is my project structure updated:

```
├── my_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── main.css
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   └── main.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── package-lock.json
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── layout.html
│   └── utils
│       ├── reader.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── serverless.yml
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work. Is it possible that an AWS SAM app / Lambda cannot do this?